# Is there a way to configure cppcheck with ability to specify positional argument number for alloc/dealloc

Tags: static-analysis, cppcheck

I work with the following functions:

- `flist_create(flist *cont)` - allocates memory for an instance of
  structure
- `flist_destroy(flist *cont)` - deallocates memory
- `flist_put(flist *cont, char *val)` - transfers memory ownership of val
  to cont (`flist_destroy` will later free that memory, as part of cleaning up cont)

For the flist itself, I can just do:

```
 <memory>
     <alloc>flist_create</alloc>
     <dealloc>flist_destroy</dealloc>
 </memory>
```

But, I can't add `flist_put` as dealloc (for freeing up the value), as cppcheck will think that flist should be freed up).

Is there any way to configure cppcheck to tell it that only specified positional argument should be considered for dealloc?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the source code of cppcheck I found the answer:

```
 <memory>
  <alloc>flist_create</alloc>
  <dealloc>flist_destroy</dealloc>
  <dealloc arg="2">flist_put</dealloc>
 </memory>
```

I find cppcheck manual to be somewhat lacking, as it doesn't have all possible use of cfg files documented...

Comment: It would be nice if someone intimately familiar with the project documented all the possible config items